# How to ignore the error of the certificate

Tags: asp.net, ssl, internet-explorer-8, activex, regedit

Sorry ,my English is poor, I have never speak English after I leave the school.
but now this problem have trouble me for a long days.

My problem: when I open the website which the security certificate is wrong ,then

## IE8 show:

===========================

There is a problem with this website's security certificate.

The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority. 
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server. 
We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website. 
Click here to close this webpage. 
Continue to this website (not recommended).

==============================

I want to open this website(https) without show this alert page 
the method may use "regedit", or change the internet Options, or by code ......and  so on.

please help me

thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via `regedit`.  Go to the following key:

```
HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

And set `WarnonBadCertRecving` to 0

If it doesn't exist, create a new DWORD called `WarnonBadCertRecving` and then set that to 0.

Alternatively, make a `.reg` file containing this and double click to run:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"WarnonBadCertRecving"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: It does work but there was a typo in the .reg snippet ("CurrentVersion" shouldn't have a space). I submitted an edit to fix it.